# Error: NJS-040: connection request timeout. Request exceeded "queueTimeout" of 60000 in Node js

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracle

My Oracle client version is 19.20.0.0.0 & node oracledb version 6.1.0

I'm running node js application randoml getting Error: NJS-040, to make connection i use pool method and made a middleware to connect...

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const logger = require('../logger');

const { PASSWORD, USERNAME, CONN_STRING } = require('../constant');
oracledb.initOracleClient();
oracledb.outFormat = oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT;

async function initializeOraclePool() {
    try {
        await oracledb.createPool({
            user: USERNAME,
            password: PASSWORD,
            connectionString: CONN_STRING,
            poolMax: 8,
            poolMin: 1,
            poolTimeout: 2000000,
        });

        logger.info(`Oracle client version is ${oracledb.oracleClientVersionString}`)

    } catch (error) {
        logger.error(error)
        console.error('Error creating Oracle connection pool:', error);
    }
}

// Middleware to acquire a database connection from the pool
async function getOracleConnection(req, res, next) {
    try {
        req.connection = await oracledb.getConnection();
        next();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error acquiring Oracle connection:', error);
        logger.error(error)
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Database connection error' });
    }
}

module.exports = { initializeOraclePool, getOracleConnection };
```

and I use like this

```
const fetchSupplierRecommendation = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { connection = {}, body = {}, query = {}, params = {} } = req;
        let { planId, srInstanceId, categorySetId, from, to } = query

        const result = await connection.execute(SQLQuery.SupplierRecommendation(planId, srInstanceId, categorySetId, from, to))
        successHandler(res, result.rows)

    } catch (error) {
        errorHandler(res, error)
    }
}
```

when I check logs I get only this error

```
0|index  | Error acquiring Oracle connection: Error: NJS-040: connection request timeout. Request exceeded "queueTimeout" of 60000
0|index  |     at Object.throwErr (/var/node/node_modules/oracledb/lib/errors.js:588:10)
0|index  |     at Timeout._onTimeout (/var/node/node_modules/oracledb/lib/pool.js:443:22)
0|index  |     at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
0|index  |     at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
0|index  |   code: 'NJS-040'
0|index  | }
```

Comment: Do you ever close connections (i.e. release them back to the pool). If you don't then that may be your problem; you open all the available connections and then never release them so that they can be reused.

Comment: Close connections, as mentioned.  Read up on [node-oracledb pools](https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#connection-pooling) and connection request queueing, and then [monitor](https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#connection-pool-monitoring) pool usage.